# TextBox ComboBox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, textbox, jcombobox

I need to create a comboBox but my ComboBox is not showing whatever I do

Here's the JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/K5bmM/

I hope someone can give me a hand :( Thanks

```
            layerName = new Ext.form.TextField({
            name: "layer-edit",
            emptyText: "(名称)",
            allowBlank: false
        });
        layerName.render('layer-edit');


        var storeData = [
            ['2', 'ログインユーザ専用']
        ]



        var comboEdit = new Ext.form.comboBox) {
            store: EditauthStore,
            editable: false,
            emptyText: "(種類)",
            displayField: "value",
            valueField: "key",
            mode: "local",
            triggerAction: "all",
            forceSelection: true
        });

        comboEdit.render('authority');
        comboEdit.setValue('2');

        EditauthStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            fields: ['key', 'value'],
            data: storeData
        });
```

Comment: Have you imported the ExtJs framework? According your code you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
   $(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
 });
});
```

Html Code

Use jquery css and js

Demo http://jsbin.com/jetoq/1/edit

Comment: Why should the OP use Jquery? Are you shure that he able or allowed to use Jquery?

Comment: i dont know but i think there is possible in two ways one is jquery and ajax method i just provide my based on the question

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code

1. You are trying to use ExtJS classes however your Fiddle doesn't point to any library
2. You are trying to use variables before defining them
3. You are trying to render ExtJS widgets with the wrong method

[image]

Also it's not clear what's the use of the text field widget you are creating before the ComboBox (does it has anything to do with your question?) nor the why you are creating an input tag on the HTML code and then trying to set other widgets as children of it (input tags don't allow inner elements).

[Here'](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/SfbFt/)s a working version of your code, I've removed the text widget since doesn't seem to have anything related to your question, you can see the code bellow, but take into account that you'll need to have ExtJS library loaded first and a valid css style for it in order to see it working.

```
        var storeData = [
            ['2', 'ログインユーザ専用']
        ];

        var EditauthStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            fields: ['key', 'value'],
            data: storeData
        });

        var comboEdit = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            store: EditauthStore,
            editable: false,
            emptyText: "(種類)",
            displayField: "value",
            valueField: "key",
            mode: "local",
            triggerAction: "all",
            forceSelection: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        comboEdit.setValue('2');
```

Comment: thanks, it did work and all of you who pointed out what is wrong with my codes.. thanks :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you, don't forget to mark answer as valid if it has been useful for you! =)